# OpenCV for Android, do I need to install OpenCV Manager separately?

Tags: android, opencv

Just started looking into OpenCV for Android. I noticed that I need to install something called OpenCV Manager before I can run the apps that use it.

Is there any way to bundle this manager with my app, so that users won't have to install it separately? It would really help if this was possible.

I haven't written an app that uses OpenCV yet, but I'm just looking ahead.

Many thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to integrate OpenCV Manager in Android App](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20259309/how-to-integrate-opencv-manager-in-android-app)

Comment: Alternate answer with screenshots, good for novices: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35135495/5611377

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for the static initialization method.

See the [documentation here](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/dev_with_OCV_on_Android.html#application-development-with-static-initialization).

Also you can check this thread:

[Static Initialization on OpenCV Android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12615712/1085483)

Answer (score 0):

I found this answer to be extremely helpful:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/40018413/6030520

You have to make sure that your OpenCV is fully functional before doing this (in other words, make sure you can build a project without errors, etc.). Also, make sure that in the settings.gradle file, you include this line of code:

```
include ':openCVLibrary330'
```

(Whatever is between the single quotes depends on the name of the openCVLibrary folder you imported. i.e. If the folder was named openCVLibrary320, then you'd enter:

```
include ':openCVLibrary320'
```

instead. The folder name is dependent on the version of OpenCV you are using.)