# Android - How I can use OpenCV without install OpenCV Manager Application

Tags: android, opencv

Is there any way to run my app with OpenCV without install an extra application (OpenCV Manager)?

I can't ask my users to install an extra app to run my application.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to integrate OpenCV Manager in Android App](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20259309/how-to-integrate-opencv-manager-in-android-app)

Answer (score 0):

Copy all the library's files.

Or simply install the manager within the app like:

```
Intent promptInstall = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
    .setDataAndType(Uri.parse("file:///path/to/org.opencv.engine.v2.14.apk"), 
                    "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
startActivity(promptInstall);
```

add this permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES" />
```