# Opencv hardware not detect in samsug galaxy s5

Tags: android, opencv, android-ndk

I am using Opencv for image processing.When i am running my application its ask for Opencv manager installation after installation in Samsung duos its working well but in Samsung galaxy S5 it is not working

Comment: This helped me lot [how-to-integrate-opencv-manager-in-android-app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20259309/how-to-integrate-opencv-manager-in-android-app)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may come from big.LITTLE architecture support, see this [thread](http://code.opencv.org/issues/3747). I advise you to run your app without OpenCV Manager.

Comment: i am already read this.Also include this lines in opencv.mk file but application ask for  opencv manager installation..                                                                                          OPENCV_INSTALL_MODULES:=on
OPENCV_LIB_TYPE:=SHARED
include D:/opencv_with/OpenCV-2.4.10-android-sdk/OpenCV-2.4.10-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/OpenCV.mk

Comment: have you read [this](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/dev_with_OCV_on_Android.html#application-development-with-static-initialization)?

Comment: yup already i read and also include this lines in opencv.mk files but app ask for installation for opencv manager.please give me a solution i am stuck.