# openCV for Android - problems in integration

Tags: java, opencv, android-library, android

I need to integrate OpenCV 2.4 in my app.First, I found that it requires OpenCV Manager for running app based on OpenCV. But, After some googling, I found another way using static initialization [here](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/dev_with_OCV_on_Android.html#application-development-with-static-initialization) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20259309/how-to-integrate-opencv-manager-in-android-app). I tried but it isn't working:

psudo code:

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

static {
    if (!OpenCVLoader.initDebug()) {
        Log.d(TAG,"init failed")
    }
}

        private BaseLoaderCallback mLoaderCallback = new BaseLoaderCallback(this) {
            @Override
            public void onManagerConnected(int status) {
                switch (status) {
                case LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS: {
                    Log.i(TAG, "OpenCV loaded successfully");
                }
                    break;
                default: {
                    super.onManagerConnected(status);
                }
                    break;
                }
            }
        };

        @Override
        public void onResume() {
            super.onResume();   
            OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION_2_4_4, this,
                    mLoaderCallback);
        }
    }
```

I tried but this isn't working. It shows the same pop-up for installing openCV Manager.

I also tried to remove `initAsync()` in onResume and `mLoaderCallback.onManagerConnected(LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS)`; but the app crashes when I use this.

Can anyone guide me to the proper way? and Please do not mark as duplicate; there are tens and hundreads of questions on SO unanswered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it to myself. You don't need to write **`.so`** extension after JNI libraries.

I wrote this in incorrect way:

```
System.loadLibrary("lib1.so");
System.loadLibrary("lib2.so");
```

After all, I found the **correct way**:

```
System.loadLibrary("lib1");
System.loadLibrary("lib2");
```

As mentioned, don't need to write `.so` extension.

Answer (score 1):

If you using Android Studio check this: https://github.com/floatlearning/android-opencv-template
Then, on Android device install a property OpenCV Manager