# Android - OpenCVLoader.initAsync run exception

Tags: android, opencv, opencv3.0

i make android program that use OpenCV , i import OpenCV 2.4.9 module to my project and it worked, but when i run the app make unfortunately error and close i found in android studio that the (**AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main**) error made because this ( **OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION_2_4_9, this, mLoaderCallback);** ) line but i can't solve this error , please help.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow.com! Please make your question a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example [M.C.V E](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also check [how to ask question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to make your post answerable.

Answer (score 0):

Download OpenCv Manager in your Android App.
Include code In your Android app

```
static {
    System.loadLibrary("native-lib");
}
 static {
    if(!OpenCVLoader.initDebug()){
        Log.d(TAG, "OpenCV not loaded");
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "OpenCV loaded");
    }
}
```

Including this should remove this error.To get a detailed description, refer to [How to integrate OpenCV Manager in Android App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20259309/how-to-integrate-opencv-manager-in-android-app?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: i download it and write this code to test that OpenCV add correctly and the app worked will and show "OpenCV loaded" , but now when open camera activity it show this error in the line of OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION_2_4_9, this, mLoaderCallback);