# OpenCV Android without OpenCV Manager

Tags: android, opencv

I know this question has been asked and answered several times here. But none of these solutions works for me:

- [Solution 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20259309/how-to-integrate-opencv-manager-in-android-app)
- [Solution 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20990010/how-to-run-opencv-related-app-without-using-opencv-manager-in-android)
- [Solution 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12335680/opencv-for-android-do-i-need-to-install-opencv-manager-separately)

Here's my code (from [this page](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/dev_with_OCV_on_Android.html#hello-opencv-sample)):

```
package com.example.helloopencv;

import org.opencv.android.BaseLoaderCallback;
import org.opencv.android.CameraBridgeViewBase;
import org.opencv.android.CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame;
import org.opencv.android.CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewListener2;
import org.opencv.android.LoaderCallbackInterface;
import org.opencv.android.OpenCVLoader;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.WindowManager;

public class HelloOpenCVActivity extends Activity implements CvCameraViewListener2 {

    protected static final String TAG = "HelloOpenCV";

    static {
        if (!OpenCVLoader.initDebug())
            Log.e(TAG, "Failed to load OpenCV!");
    }

    private BaseLoaderCallback mLoaderCallback = new BaseLoaderCallback(this) {
        @Override
        public void onManagerConnected(int status) {
            switch (status) {
            case LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS:
                {
                    Log.i(TAG, "OpenCV loaded successfully");
                    mOpenCvCameraView.enableView();
                } break;
                default:
                    super.onManagerConnected(status);
                break;
            }
        }
    };

    private CameraBridgeViewBase mOpenCvCameraView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.i(TAG, "called onCreate");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_hello_open_cv);
        mOpenCvCameraView = (CameraBridgeViewBase) findViewById(R.id.HelloOpenCVView);
        mOpenCvCameraView.setVisibility(SurfaceView.VISIBLE);
        mOpenCvCameraView.setCvCameraViewListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION_2_4_6, this, mLoaderCallback);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause()
    {
        super.onPause();
        if (mOpenCvCameraView != null)
            mOpenCvCameraView.disableView();
    }

    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (mOpenCvCameraView != null)
            mOpenCvCameraView.disableView();
    }

    public void onCameraViewStarted(int width, int height) {
    }

    public void onCameraViewStopped() {
    }

    public Mat onCameraFrame(CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
        return inputFrame.rgba();
    }
}
```

I have also followed the settings [here](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/dev_with_OCV_on_Android.html#application-development-with-static-initialization). However, every time I try to run the code in my device (Galaxy Note 2), I am always asked to install OpenCV Manager package. Could I have missed something? Anybody can help me?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to integrate OpenCV Manager in Android App](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20259309/how-to-integrate-opencv-manager-in-android-app)

Comment: Solution 4:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/35135495/5611377

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OpenCV in Android Studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27406303/opencv-in-android-studio)

Answer (score 10):

Add

`mLoaderCallback.onManagerConnected(LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS);`

after `mOpenCvCameraView.setCvCameraViewListener(this);` in onCreate()

and remove `OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION_2_4_6, this, mLoaderCallback);` from onResume()

If everything else is correctly done, this should not ask for OpenCV Manager.

**EDIT :**

it will be better if you put below code inside **`onResume`** method of your `Activity`

`mLoaderCallback.onManagerConnected(LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS);`

Comment: Hello there, I have got the same problem but after I insert the line mLoaderCallback.onManagerConnected(LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS) to my code I have got bunch of errors and my app crashed. The errors are ClassNotFoundException:com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_calib3d and same error on opencv_highgui library. Would you please help me?

Comment: Sorry for the delayed answer. If you still have the problem you should have to check if all of the required files are in the libs folder. For static initialization you need to have all of the .so files in the armeabi etc folders. I think it is mentioned also in the tutorial that opencv provided.

Comment: it should be inside `onResume` to make it work when user moves out of the app and comes back.

Answer (score 4):

Copy all the library's files.

Or simply install the manager within the app like:

```
Intent promptInstall = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
    .setDataAndType(Uri.parse("file:///path/to/org.opencv.engine.v2.14.apk"), 
                    "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
startActivity(promptInstall);
```

add this permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES" />
```